# Wrong parameters when setting up sensor trigger

Tags: c, sensors, zephyr-rtos

I'm trying to integrate accelerometer MCP6050 in my Zephyr project but I'm having some problem. sensor_trigger_set returns -88 which points to invalid argument. It's fairly basic trigger I think;

```
struct sensor_trigger trig;
trig.type = SENSOR_TRIG_DATA_READY;
trig.chan = SENSOR_CHAN_ACCEL_XYZ;

int rc = sensor_trigger_set(accelDev, &trig, trigger_handler);

if (rc != 0) {
    printf("Failed to set trigger: %d\n", rc);
    return 0;
}
```

It then runs the printf and returns the application. Does anyone have a tip?

Comment: I assume you mean the MPU6050 accelerometer. What does your devicetree look like for the device? Does it have the `int-gpios` property set? Is `CONFIG_MPU6050_TRIGGER` set in your config for this project?